# OpenCV shows image more pale than videos

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video, imshow

I have a python code, where I load an image into a window and later overwrite it with different videos.
The image and the first frame of the videos is the same, to be exact, I extracted the frame from position one from the first video with Shotcut and used the frame to blend over into each video. However there is always a jump in coloring when the video starts. I first thought it might be an issue of .jpg compression, but this cannot be, since I used the .jpg file for blending in all but the first video (edited them with a video editing software) and there always is a shift in color. I have the same effect with a rendered animation and the first frame as a jpg from such as well, but it is barely visible with this video. However, due to data privacy, I can't upload the videos, but here are the images:
[image] [image: Video Frame]

The difference is barely visible, but I had my mouse somewhere at the nose (on the right side, where nothing changed) and as you can see at the bottom, where it shows the RGB values, even though I didn't move the mouse, R and G increased, while B decreased.
My python code:

```
#Imports    
img = cv2.imread(path + "name.jpg")
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(20)
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(path + "vid.mp4")
while True:
     ret, frame = self.vid.read()
     if ret:
        cv2.imshow("Image", frame)
        cv2.waitKey(20)
     else:
        vid.release()
        break
```

In this case it is not so serious, but the video with the real person has a lot more reddish, so the increase in red is clearly visible.
I am sure they are the same frames, for I have made a screenshot before sending any command to start the video and made a screenshot at the end of the video (the video contains a blend over back to the jpg).
The videos are .mp4, encoded in H.264 video stream.

Comment: it looks a compression issue.. try to extract the first frame from the video and save in png format, then check the RGB values of a specific point (you can print the values instead of using mouse hoover). If they are the same the problem lies in the process of extracting the frame from the video..

Comment: It could be related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68629271/opencv-read-write-video-color-difference). It's hard to say for sure, because you didn't post any information about `vid.mp4`. It could also be related to the differences between "full range" and "limited range". JPEG uses full range YUV420 - range [0, 255], while the default range for video is [16, 235] so some accuracy is lost (there are ways to encode the video in "full range"). Some accuracy is also lost by video compression.

Comment: How can you be sure the frames are the first frames you extracted ? I am suspicious you really got the first frames to compare ? Can you please share how you got them ?

Comment: Well, I went to frame 0 from the video in Shotcut, clicked on export Frame -> jpg. :D

Comment: **shutcut**? that different decoder, expect different results. -- both pictures look the same, colorspace-wise. they don't demonstrate anything. -- there is insufficient information to simply conclude that it's "a bug in OpenCV". if there's a bug, it's probably in video decoding or image encoding, all of which happen in other libraries (ffmpeg, libpng). likely a loss of color space information or inconsistent defaults (going by your description, not the pictures)

Comment: @Rackwitz You can barely see it with those indeed. But you can clearly see it with the others. Sadly I cannot post them, since obviously there is a real person on them and I don't have the right to publish images of her. But when you check out the other post, you can see that it results to the very same issue and the solution over there is pretty detailed in how to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

So, apparently this is indeed a bug in OpenCV, how Rotem pointed out in the comments.
A work-around can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68629271/opencv-read-write-video-color-difference) with GStream, though it brings some down-sides. (As mentioned in the comments GStream is not appropriate for not streamed videos.) The compression of the video might also need to be considered.